# Android Preferences List Files

Tags: java, android, preferences

I am trying to make a preferences option that will show the name of all of the files in a specific directory. I have looked, but I haven't seen anything that can do this. Is there a way? Thanks!

William

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
File dir = new File(path_dir); 
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

will get you an array of all the files under `path_dir` directory. 
Iterate over it and and append files[i].getName() to an array of CharSequence.

```
CharSequence[] entries = ...;
ListPreference lp = new ListPreference(this);
lp.setEntries(entries);
lp.setEntryValues(entries);
```